# UIButton in Objective - c (programmatically)

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

hy,

I'm new in objective-c. I'm trying to add a button into my UIView. But I can't see the button in my application. I tried a lot but nothing worked.
I know there are many posts about that but no solution worked at my code.

PinViewController.m:

```
#import "PinViewController.h"
@implementation PinViewController
@synthesize view,one;
-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    UIButton *btnname = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btnname setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnname.frame = CGRectMake(28, 31, 42, 21);
    [self.view addSubview:btnname];
}
```

PinViewController.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>   
@interface PinViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *view;
@property UIButton *one;


@end
```

In appdeligate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window.rootViewController = [[PinViewController alloc]init];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take from your question that you specifically want to *not* have storyboards or xibs. That's a perfectly legitimate but somewhat infrequent choice, and it has it's pros and cons.

You are writing a wrong constructor for PinViewController, which should be a subclass of UIViewController, but it class UIView's constructor instead (which is *not* its parent).

The other thing is that you shouldn't create (and synthesise) a new property 'view', it is already there for UIViewController, and this way the default setters/getters will be overridden. And you create your new view by setting the property. You'll also have to specify frame otherwise it will have no size. So it is:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Third problem is that viewDidLoad was never called. According to documentation at [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad)

> This method is called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView method.

This does not happen since you don't create the view in the loadView method. The loadView method, in turn, is not called at all, because you create the view in the constructor. So the solution is to not override the constructor at all, but do instead:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}
```

(Alternatively, you can just call viewDidLoad manually from the constructor after creating the view, which is less nice but does the job)

Comment: thank you for your help :) what do you mean with [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow. can you show me a code example?

Comment: Sure, just use self.window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow; 
In this case, it's the same as writing [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]; 
See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/keyWindow

Comment: @user3717582 The advice about the window is wrong, your code is correct in that respect (Xcode probably auto-generated this for you).

Comment: @ZsoltSzatmari It appears that the OP is creating the UI programmatically. In that case he _must_ create a `UIWindow` himself. Only if the UI is created via .xib / storyboard is there no need to manually create a `UIWindow`.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong about the window, I changed my answer and pointed out other problems with the code, and tried it myself.

Comment: Removed downvote since you edited your question. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried your solution and I could change the background color of view but still no button is visible.

Comment: I found a third problem and extended my answer, hope this helps!